# Tkinter: display the list of items in tkinter text GUI widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to display each row and column with correct values, but using tkinter widget i dont see the expected result. Expect is

```
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')
('aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee')
('!@', '%^', '&*', '@#', '@$')
('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')
```

but only `('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')` is displayed in all the rows. please help me to sort out the problem:

```
from tkinter import *
top=Tk()
for t in [("1","2","3","4","5"),("aa","bb","cc","dd","ee"),("!@","%^","&*","@#","@$"),("A","B","C","D","E")]: 

for x in range(4):
    for y in range(5):
        w = Text(top, width=15, height=2)
        w.grid(row=x,column=y)
        w.insert(END, t[y])


top.state("zoomed")
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: `for y in range(5):` fishy part?

Comment: I want 4 rows and 5 columns, that is why "for y in range(5):"

Comment: see if the answer posted below helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need this loop:

```
for t in [("1","2","3","4","5"),("aa","bb","cc","dd","ee"),("!@","%^","&*","@#","@$"),("A","B","C","D","E")]:
```

Instead:

```
from tkinter import *
top=Tk()
t = [("1","2","3","4","5"),("aa","bb","cc","dd","ee"),("!@","%^","&*","@#","@$"),("A","B","C","D","E")]

for x in range(4):
    for y in range(5):
            w = Text(top, width=15, height=2)
            w.grid(row=x,column=y)
            w.insert(END, t[x][y])

top.state("zoomed")
top.mainloop()
```

**OUTPUT**:

[image: out]

Comment: Which is fine until a new item is added. Is it not more pythonic to do `for row in t:` and `for column in row:` rather than using `range`?